# Android ListView with EditText lose IN EDIT values if scroll up/down

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

There are so many similar question but none cover my case.
I've a ListView with an EditText which is in Editing phase.
If I scroll the list so my in edit row goes out of view I lose the entering value.

I'm already using OnFocusChangeListener to "store" changed values when user move from a row to another, but this event isn't fired when editing row goes out of view.

This is my actual code:

```
public enum FieldType {
    UNDEFINED, TITLE, EDIT, CHECK;
}

public enum EditType {
    INTEGER, FLOAT
}

private abstract class BaseField {
    public FieldType type = FieldType.UNDEFINED;
}       

private class TitleField extends BaseField {
    public int titleID;

    public TitleField(int titleID) {
        this.type = FieldType.TITLE;
        this.titleID = titleID;
    }
}

private class EditField extends BaseField {
    public String code;
    public int captionID;
    public String value;
    public String unit;
    public String decimal;
    public String minimum;
    public String maximum;

    public EditField(String code, int captionID, String value, String unit, String decimal, String minimum, String maximum) {
        this.type = FieldType.EDIT;
        this.code = code;
        this.captionID = captionID;
        this.value = value;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.decimal = decimal;
        this.minimum = minimum;
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }
}

private class CheckField extends BaseField {
    public String code;
    public int captionID;
    public boolean value;
    public String unit;

    public CheckField(String code, int captionID, boolean value, String unit) {
        this.type = FieldType.CHECK;
        this.code = code;
        this.captionID = captionID;
        this.value = value;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}

private class TitleFieldViewHolder {
    public TextView textTitle = null;
}

private class EditFieldViewHolder {
    public TextView textCode = null;
    public TextView textCaption = null;
    public EditText editValue = null;
    public TextView textUnit = null;
}

private class CheckFieldViewHolder {
    public TextView textCode = null;
    public TextView textCaption = null;
    public CheckBox checkValue = null;
    public TextView textUnit = null;
}

private BaseField Fields[] = {
        new TitleField(R.string.general_settings),
        new EditField("PG-01", R.string.legs_number, "4", "", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-02", R.string.operating_mode, "0", "", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-03", R.string._500mm_position_mode, "3", "", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-04", R.string.enable_additional_lift, "0", "", "", "", ""),
        new EditField("PG-05", R.string.mechanical_release_mode, "0", "", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-06", R.string.delta_count_mechanical_release, "50", "bit", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-07", R.string.max_misalignment_bridge, "150", "bit", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-08", R.string.min_delta_inclinometers, "10", "bit", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-09", R.string.max_bridge_height, "3000", "bit", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-10", R.string.min_bridge_height, "0", "bit", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-11", R.string.range_limit_approaching_bridge, "100", "bit", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-12", R.string.enable_input_sa, "0", "", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-13", R.string.enable_working_positions, "0", "", "", "", ""), 

        new TitleField(R.string.time_settings),
        new EditField("PG-14", R.string.mechanical_release_time, "2.000", "s", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-15", R.string.bridge_stabilization_time, "2.000", "s", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-16", R.string.waiting_time_c1_start, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-17", R.string.waiting_time_ev2_start, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-18", R.string.waiting_time_ev3_start, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-19", R.string.waiting_time_c1_on, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-20", R.string.waiting_time_ev1_on, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""),
        new EditField("PG-21", R.string.waiting_time_ev2_on, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-22", R.string.waiting_time_ev3_on, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""),
        new EditField("PG-23", R.string.waiting_time_c1_off, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-24", R.string.waiting_time_ev1_off, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""),
        new EditField("PG-25", R.string.waiting_time_ev2_off, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""), 
        new EditField("PG-26", R.string.waiting_time_ev3_off, "0.100", "s", "", "", ""),
};

private ListView mListView;
private ListViewAdapter mListViewAdapter;

void init() {
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    mListViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter();
    mListView.setAdapter(mListViewAdapter);
}

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ListViewAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Fields.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (Fields[position].type) {
            case TITLE:
                return 0;
            case EDIT:
                return 1;
            case CHECK:
                return 2;
        }
        return 1;

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        switch (Fields[position].type) {

            case TITLE:
                TitleFieldViewHolder titleHolder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.title_field_item, null);
                    titleHolder = new TitleFieldViewHolder();
                    titleHolder.textTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
                    convertView.setTag(titleHolder);
                } else {
                    titleHolder = (TitleFieldViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                TitleField titleField = (TitleField) Fields[position];
                titleHolder.textTitle.setText(getResources().getString(titleField.titleID));
                break;

            case EDIT:
                EditFieldViewHolder editHolder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_field_item, null);
                    editHolder = new EditFieldViewHolder();
                    editHolder.textCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCode);
                    editHolder.textCaption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCaption);
                    editHolder.editValue = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editValue);
                    editHolder.textUnit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textUnit);
                    convertView.setTag(editHolder);
                } else {
                    editHolder = (EditFieldViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                final EditField editField = (EditField) Fields[position];
                editHolder.textCode.setText(editField.code);
                editHolder.textCaption.setText(getResources().getString(editField.captionID));
                editHolder.editValue.setText(editField.value);
                editHolder.textUnit.setText(editField.unit);

                //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
                editHolder.editValue.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (!hasFocus){
                            EditText editValue = (EditText) v;
                            editField.value = editValue.getText().toString();
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;

            case CHECK:
                CheckFieldViewHolder checkHolder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.check_field_item, null);
                    checkHolder = new CheckFieldViewHolder();
                    checkHolder.textCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCode);
                    checkHolder.textCaption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCaption);
                    checkHolder.checkValue = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkValue);
                    checkHolder.textUnit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textUnit);
                    convertView.setTag(checkHolder);
                } else {
                    checkHolder = (CheckFieldViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                CheckField checkField = (CheckField) Fields[position];
                checkHolder.textCode.setText(checkField.code);
                checkHolder.textCaption.setText(getResources().getString(checkField.captionID));
                checkHolder.checkValue.setChecked(checkField.value);
                checkHolder.textUnit.setText(checkField.unit);
                break;

        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: you must set unique tag to each row and worked with that

Comment: Shayan, you mean that I've to create a new convertView and editHolder for earch EDIT row ? I don't understand your sentence. Thank you for support... If can help I pushed entire project to this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/kryqqcqi7gsx85g/omerlifmanager.tar.gz